# JAX-RS Same @Path Identifier in two Services

Tags: web-services, jersey, jax-rs, restful-architecture

I am having the below scenario while implementing JAX-RS web service.

Service A:

```
@Path("/customer/{customerId}")
public interface ICustomerDataUsageService{

@GET
@Path("/datausage")
public Response getCustomerDataUsage();

//other methods...
}
```

Service B:

```
@Path("/")
public interface IHelpDeskService{

@GET
@Path("/customer/{customerId}")
public Response getCustomer();

//other methods...
}
```

After deployment only the Service A is working (Its registered after the Service B). For the second one I am getting HTTP 404 error.

Unfortunately we cannot change the interfaces since its provided by another entity. We are only having control of the implementation classes for these.

I am using [Jersey-2.22](https://jersey.github.io/).

Is there any way out to have both these services working without changing the interfaces.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you register service to other application with other `@ApplicationPath`?

Comment: @user7294900 I don't think that will work because one application path will need to overlap the other

Comment: @vikajramun but if only 1 service is registered to parent path as `/neverbeenused` it will have different paths

Comment: @user7294900 I believe he wants `/customer/{customerId}` to be handled by one resource class, and `/customer/{customerId}/datausage` to be handled by a different resource class. I understood it as he didn't want to change the paths.

Comment: You should file a bug report with whoever wrote this code. Because this definitely _is_ a bug.

Comment: FYI, the `@Path` on the interface is ignored. The `@Path` is supposed to go on the concrete class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug and was fixed by the API team by correcting the API.
The fix looks as below:

Service A:

```
@Path("/customer")
public interface ICustomerDataUsageService{

@GET
@Path("/{customerId}/datausage")
public Response getCustomerDataUsage();

//other methods also got /{customerId} added in path
}
```

Service B:

```
@Path("/")
public interface IHelpDeskService{

@GET
@Path("/customer/{customerId}")
public Response getCustomer();

//other methods...
}
```